# Apply pd.get_dummies() on string type columns of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [6.6, -5.2, 2.1, 3.3, 1.1],
              'b': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'],
              'c': ['kfr', 'kfr', 'lu', 'ku', 'lu'],
              'd': ['t', 's', 's', 't', 'a']})
```

All the dtypes (columns b, c, d) are of type string.

If I call `df = df.convert_dtypes()`, and then call `pd.get_dummies()`, **nothing happens**.

But when I call it on just one column of the dataframe, it works.

Why is this happening? Is it a bug?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @richardec the same if I would provide object. I mean the same OHE.

Comment: What's the _problem_? `pd.get_dummies(df)` returns a new dataframe with these columns: `b_a  b_b  b_c  c_kfr  c_ku  c_lu  d_a  d_s  d_t`

Comment: Do you mean your original ```df``` is not modified Maybe you need to assign it back? ```dum_df = pd.get_dummies(df)``` ?

Comment: @sophocles no, my original dataframe doesn't have any object dtypes, but strings, floats, integers etc.
When I am trying to apply the get_dummies() on string type columns, it doesn't do the ohe. When I convert it to object dtype, it works.

Comment: @richardec see my comment above

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't do the one-hot-encoding"? It raises an error? The new dataframe is identical to the old one? It's not what you expect? Your computer explodes? What?

Comment: I'm a bit exasperated because I run your two code snippets in the question, it they seem to work for me. I can't tell if it's erroring for you, or just not quite what you want.

Comment: @richardec it returns the same dataframe without doing ohe.

Comment: So `df = pd.get_dummies(df)` does nothing?

Comment: Try doing df = df.convert_dtypes() and run pd.get_dummies(df)

Comment: @richardec yes, does nothing. The whole story is that I am getting a very long dataset (key, value, request_id) as dataframe. I am pivoting it and get objects dtypes for all columns. I need to fill NAs, but first of all I need to convert to the relevant dtypes. I am doing it using convert_dtypes() that converts objects to strings for some columns (which are strings). When I want to perform ohe, it won't apply it and return the same dataframe. Then I am applying the get_dummies() on the string columns (by doing convert_dtypes(convert_strings=False) ) it works.

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you mean. You should definitely add the fact that ran `convert_dtypes` to the question, because that makes the difference.

Comment: So before you run `convert_dtypes`, string cols are `dtype('O')`. Afterwards, they're `string[python]`.

Comment: Yes it's a bit complicated I am trying to preprocess the dataset for the Neo4j GraphSAGE algorithm in Python. That is why I need to feed it with "clean" numeric data.

Comment: @richardec yes they are objects. I have solved it by configuring the convert_dtypes() to not converting to strings. But why pd.get_dummies() doesn't work on strings?

Comment: @richardec what do you think, why it doesn't work on strings? Did you manage to reproduce it?

Comment: I was able to reproduce, and I'm investigating exactly why this occurs.

Comment: OP, I'm not following everything in the comments, but there [doesn't seem to be a problem](https://i.imgur.com/9pPkkCh.png) given just the text of your question.  Could you either update your question to reproduce your problem, or provide the expected output and how it's different from the output of `pd.get_dummies`?

Comment: @user1717828 please see the above comment of richardec, he have reproduced the issue.

Comment: @richardec do you have any insights about the issue?

Comment: @user1717828 there isn't a problem per the question itself, but if you say `df = df.convert_dtypes()` before `pd.get_dummies()`, you'll see that, indeed, nothing happens.

Comment: @richardec thanks :) did you discover anything interesting?

Comment: @SteveS No, I wasn't. I'm really not sure why this is happening. I'd venture to say that it might be a bug.

Comment: @richardec I will post an answer together with the fact that it's a bug.

Comment: @SteveS I wrote an answer summing my conclusions.

Comment: @richardec thank you so much! I have already submitted a bug to pandas dev.

Comment: Nice, I'll watch it.

Comment: @richardec seems that nobody found the issue there. Are you in contact with the pandas dev team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I have no idea why this might be occurring, especially since it works for single columns. I'm guessing it's a bug, because there seem to be quite a few of them centered around the `pd.NA` type (which `convert_dtypes` is in support of.)

I recommend opening a bug report at https://github.com/pandas/pandas-dev.